# Bootstrap Carousel ignores data-interval

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm trying to create a Bootstrap Carousel with a video in the first slide. Everything is working as expected except that the carousel does not take the data-interval into account on the first run of the first slide. When we go back to the slide from another one, it works as expected.

I did a minimal repro here:
https://www.codeply.com/p/avdtdpw8ie

We can see that the first slide gets displayed for about 1 second on the first run, but on its second run it gets displayed for 5 seconds as defined by the data-interval attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `data-interval` attributes directly on the HTML, you can set the interval using jQuery. This will trigger the Carousel once it's loaded:

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 1000
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="width: 400px; height: 300px">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" alt="First slide" src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" alt="Second slide" src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" alt="Third slide" src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More info [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/#individual-carousel-item-interval).

Comment: Adding the quotes does not change the issue I have. At the start, the first slide is shown for ~2s (~1s of initialization time I guess). So on initialization, the carousel does not take into account the time define on the carousel item. If you switch slide and switch back to the first slide, the interval is correct. You have to refresh the page to reproduce the error.

Comment: Like you mentioned, there's a slight loading time. I updated the answer with an alternate time interval loading (using jQuery), give it a try and see if this does the trick for you.

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to mention, I want my carousel to display for 5s as defined on the first `carousel-item`. The delay does not bother me. [In the meantime, I've found a resource that says this is by design.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/29200) I hope there's a way around this, because that would make some _really ugly code_ .